# .update Not working -- Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

For some odd reason, my `.update` function isn't properly functioning. I thought the selector of `this._id` is the issue here, but I tried passing in a raw ID of one of the items in my database instead. With `good_input`, the `.insert` content is all stored in the database but the `.update` is merely skipped looking at the results.

```
 Template.newInstitution.events({
    'click #form_institution': function () {
      var inst_name = $('#name')[0].value;
      var inst_type = $('#type')[0].value;
      var inst_school = $('#school')[0].value;
      var inst_desc = $('#description')[0].value;
      var good_input = true;
      if (inst_name === "") {
        $('#name')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a name";
        $('#nameDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_type === "") {
        $('#type')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a type";
        $('#typeDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_school === "") {
        $('#school')[0].placeholder = "Please enter your affiliated school";
        $('#schoolDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_desc === "") {
        $('#description')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a description";
        $('#descDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (good_input) {
        Institutions.insert({
          admin: Meteor.userId(),
          title: inst_name,
          type: inst_type,
          school: inst_school,
         description: inst_desc
        });
        Institutions.update({_id: this._id},
          {$push: {
            members: Meteor.userId()
          }}
        );
        Router.go('songs');
      }
    }
  });
```

https://bpaste.net/show/befaba419c19

Would someone identify the issue here and explain the cause of it?

Comment: https://bpaste.net/show/8bc51e4e8a4b -- Here's some other relevant snippets from the js file but not related to this template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you think that `this._id` is being set?  Unless there is some further context not visible, there's no such thing.  While I agree that you should just include the data in the initial `insert`, probably what you're looking for is `var id = Institutions.insert({...})` and using `id` instead of `this._id`.

Comment: Yep. Got it. Actually answered my own question :)

Answer (score 1):

This was the fix. Basically, I can just set an array in the original statement and use $push later.

```
  Template.newInstitution.events({
    'click #form_institution': function () {
      var inst_name = $('#name')[0].value;
      var inst_type = $('#type')[0].value;
      var inst_school = $('#school')[0].value;
      var inst_desc = $('#description')[0].value;
      var good_input = true;
      if (inst_name === "") {
        $('#name')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a name";
        $('#nameDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_type === "") {
        $('#type')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a type";
        $('#typeDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_school === "") {
        $('#school')[0].placeholder = "Please enter your affiliated school";
        $('#schoolDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (inst_desc === "") {
        $('#description')[0].placeholder = "Please enter a description";
        $('#descDiv').addClass("has-error");
        good_input = false;
      }
      if (good_input) {
        Institutions.insert({
          admin: Meteor.userId(),
          title: inst_name,
          type: inst_type,
          school: inst_school,
          description: inst_desc,
          members: [Meteor.userId()]
        });
        Router.go('songs');
      }
    }
  });
```